# Delete lines between two patterns in shell

Tags: bash, shell, perl, awk, sed

I need to delete multiple lines between `,` and `(` including both the pattern as well just at the first occurrence.

**Example**

```
Test ,

 this 

is the 
deletion 
part 
(
done...
```

**Expected Output**

```
Test 
done
```

I've tried the following using sed to achieve the above output but it just returns the entire file data.

```
sed 's/,*(//' file
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your code (the way you intend it to work, not the way it does work), it seems to be very unrelated to your described goal, which makes the question ambiguos and unclear.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have provided an example of how I intend the code to work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is more suitable here:

```
awk '/,/{p=1; sub(/[ \t]*,.*/, ""); print} !p; /\(/{p=0}' file

Test
done
```

Alternatively you can also use `perl`:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\h*,.*\(//s' file
```

Or this regex with a negated character class that doesn't require `s` modifier:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\h*,[^(]*\(//' file
```

Comment: `[\s\S]` nice `:-)`

Comment: Other option is to use `s` modifier as in `'s~,(?s).*\(~~'`

Comment: perl more often uses modifiers outside of regex `s/...//s`

Comment: @anubhava Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no reason to avoid the usual slash delimiters for the Perl substitution, and `[\s\S]`is a very extended way of writing `.` with the `/s` modifier. `perl -i -0777 's/,.*\(//s' file` is the more usual way of writing this.

Comment: Probably want `[^(]*` instead of `.*` (to stop at the first `(`).

Comment: Thanks, Indeed and that doesn't even require `s` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed '/Test/,/done/{//!d;s/ ,$//}' file
```

`/Test/,/done/`: from line matching `Test` up to next line matching `done`:

- `//!d` deletes all lines except those matching the addresses(`Test ,` and `done`)
- `s/ ,$//` removes first occurrence `,` from the address

Comment: @bfontaine I added some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/,[^(]*(//g' file
```

Slurp the entire file into memory and global replace any characters between a `,` and `(` with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/ ,|\.../,"")}NR==1;END{print}' file

Test
done
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants - it should delete from "," until "(". (Also it would be good to have a little explanation of how it works!)